# Trying to write a new file in Discord.py and nothing is happening

Tags: python, file, discord, discord.py, os.walk

I'm pretty new to Python and Discord.py so I apologize if the answer to this question should have been more obvious to me.

I want to be able to save data from a server with my bot and look over the data if I have to, so I decided the most efficient way to do this would be to have my bot write text files for each server to contain all their data.

Below is my code.

```
import discord
from discord.ext, import commands
import os

@bot.event
async def on_server_join(server):
  print('Joined ' + server.name)
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Physix'): # Creating the file for the server if it doesn't already exist
    if server.name + '.txt' in files:
      print('File for ' + server.name + ' already exists')
    else:
      newFile = open(server.name + '.txt', 'w+')
      newFile.write(server.name + '\n')
      newFile.close()
      print('File for ' + server.name + ' created')
```

My problem is that when I run my code and have the bot rejoin the server, no file is created. Nothing is even printed either, except for "Joined [serverName]" which runs before the file searching and writing begins. The compiler doesn't show any errors.

I looked up that the best way to see if a file already exists is by using os.walk, so that's the method I'm using here. Is there a more efficient way to save data while being able to access them that I'm not aware of?

Another question I have is when you create a new file, how does Python know where to store it? There doesn't seem to be any sort of parameter as to where the file should be stored. It just creates the file.

If this question has been asked before, please link me to it, but I wasn't really able to find one that helped me with this issue I'm having here. Thanks!

Comment: The working directory of a python program is the directory (folder) that the program is "in", in the same way that you're "in" a folder when you're navigating through Explorer on a Windows computer.  This is the directory that you use by default, when reading, writing, and creating files.  This is by default the directory from which you execute python, which is usually the one where your `.py` file is located.  You can change this directory using `os.chdir`, or specify a path to a file in another directory, like `C:\test.txt` or `../../test.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
@client.event
async def on_server_join(server):
    with open('info.txt','w') as file:
        file.write("Server name: " + server.name)
        print('File for ' + server.name + ' created')
```

Comment: I should add if you want to stack the server names into the same .txt file you can use : _with open('info.txt','a') as file:_ instead